# The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable

Tags: web-platform-installer

Web platform installer 4.5 was downloaded from [official site](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
During istallation got problem: it doesn't see `wpi.msi` file in the folder. But when I open this folder in explorer I see this file. Currently I have Web platform installer **4.0** and want to upgrate to version **4.5**. So I can't install Web Platform Installer 4.5.

[image: wpi.msi missing]

Comment: I also have this trouble with Web platform installer 4.6/5.0

Comment: I have this problem with 5.0.

Answer (score 4):

Better late then never!

Try using this solution, looks like you have a corrupt registry key(s).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Comment: You're a life saver! :) Don't forget to reboot after running the Microsoft tool found when following the link.